# Array error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I'm very new to Java, currently learning arrays.
So I was making this little program to input gas used and miles traveled to calculate miles per gallon, but whenever I run the program I get an error at line 21 (miles[counter] = input.nextInt();) the error says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at GasMileage.inputGasAndMiles(GasMileage.java:21)
at GasMileage.main(GasMileage.java:44)
```

I have no idea what this means nor do I know how to fix it, It'd be great if I could get some help on this.

```
int counter = 0;
int[] gallons, miles = new int[trips];

public void inputGasAndMiles(){

    for(counter = 0; counter <= trips; counter++){
        System.out.print("\nInput miles traveled: ");
        miles[counter] = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input gallons of fuel used: ");
        gallons[counter] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

EDIT

```
public void askTrips(){
    System.out.print("How many trips would you like to calculate for: ");
    trips = input.nextInt();
}
```

Stack trace:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    GasMileage gas = new GasMileage();

    gas.askTrips();
    gas.inputGasAndMiles();
    gas.calculate();
    gas.display();
}
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `trips`?

Comment: `counter < trips` will fix

Comment: also, don't forget to initialize gallons.

Comment: @Legend the initial value is set by the user, I forgot to show the code above.

Answer (score 3):

it should be `for (counter = 0; counter < trips; counter++)`

because, array index starts from zero, so max index would be `(size-1)` not `size`

**EDIT:**

```
int trips= 0; //any +ve value
int[] gallons =  new int[trips], miles = new int[trips];

public void inputGasAndMiles(){

for(counter = 0; counter < trips; counter++){
    System.out.print("\nInput miles traveled: ");
    miles[counter] = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Input gallons of fuel used: ");
    gallons[counter] = input.nextInt();
}
```

}

Comment: This does not provide the same error. `trips` is most likely 0, resulting in the index out of range at index 0.

Comment: still it wont go out of index

Comment: It does not answer his question. An array of size 0 does not have an element at index 0.

Comment: @WotWat, make sure `trips` is designated initially above 0.

Comment: @Legend then how will it pass the case 0<0 ? (where 1st 0 is start index, and 2nd is size)

Comment: It does not answer his question. Yes this is a problem, but it is not the current problem he has right now. `trips` is not greater than 0 when it gets assigned to the array's length. That is what is causing the error he posted.

Comment: @Legend yes, its not the answer, its already edited now. But its necessory to correct someone giving wrong information.

Comment: can u post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(counter = 0; counter <= trips; counter++)
```

change it to :

```
for(counter = 0; counter < trips; counter++)
```

The size of your `gallons` array is `trips` .Since the first Index starts with `0` so the last index of your `gallons` array will be `trips-1`. And in your code you are trying to access the element at index `trips` when (counter == trips) in for loop becomes true, this leading to `ArrayIndexOutOfBounException`

Comment: Yes, remember, arrays start at 0 not 1, so if you want to iterate over an array of 10 elements, you need to go from 0 to 9

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
counter <= trips
```

to this

```
counter < trips
```

in the `for` construct there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int counter = 0;
int[] gallons, miles = new int[trips];

public void inputGasAndMiles() {
    for(counter = 0; counter < trips; counter++) {
        System.out.print("\nInput miles traveled: ");
        miles[counter] = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input gallons of fuel used: ");
        gallons[counter] = input.nextInt();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for(counter = 0; counter <= trips; counter++)
```

to

```
for(counter = 0; counter < trips; counter++)
```

index of array  start from 0 to (length -1 )